# Maxima 2D plot -- How to set axes equal

Tags: plot, maxima

For example, what is a code for plotting y = x so that y- and x-axis have the same scale ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxima, by default, uses gnuplot to produce 2d graphics.

If you're using this default, then you need to set the `gnuplot_preamble`, e.g.

```
plot2d(x, [x,-1,1], [gnuplot_preamble, "set size ratio -1"])$
```

Note the `-1` means that *gnuplot  tries to set the scales so that the unit has the same length on both axes*, while `+1` sets the aspect ratio ignoring the axis scales.
To make this the default, type

```
set_plot_option ([gnuplot_preamble, "set size ratio -1"])$
```

If you want to find out more about the gnuplot size options, run `gnuplot` from your terminal and type `help set size` into the console.

---

n.b. Most basic questions you can have about Maxima can be found somewhere in their mailing list archive: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/maximalist.html

Comment: It surely worked. Is there a way to "set size ratio 1" by default ?

Answer (score 8):

The axes can be made the same size using the same_xy option:

```
plot2d(x, [x,-1,1], [same_xy]);
```

or

```
plot2d(x, [x,-1,1], [same_xy, true]);
```

There is a same_xyz option for three dimensional plots.

Comment: The `"set size ratio -1"` option didn't work (at least with `wximplicit_plot`), and yours finally did.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `draw` or `draw3d` function (or animated versions of those), then you have to pass the `proportional_axes` graphic option as an argument.

For example `proportional_axes = xy` in 2D.

See more:
http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/de/maxima_42.html
(Search for "proportional_axes".)